# Isolating 4 bits in a 32 bit number in MIPS

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips, mips32

I'm new to MIPS and I'm trying to find out whether I can actually send in 4 bits
to a MIPS function using $a0, for example, or whether I have to send a 32-bit number
and just use the convention that the first 4 bits of that number are the 4 bits of interest.

Since the registers only store 32-bit words, I'm assuming you have to provide a 32-bit word,
but if it's not necessary I would really like to know how to avoid it.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you "send the number"? Can you show the code - and maybe explain why you care about whether you send 8, 16 or 32 bits?

Comment: Sorry, I used C parlance there. Basically, I'm creating functions that scramble 4, 8, 16, and 32 bits. The 32-bit function calls the scramble16 function, which in turn calls scramble8, and so forth. So, I'm looking to isolate a given 16 bits of a 32-bit number, and put those bits in an argument register so that scramble16 can do work on those 16 bits. I'm just trying to find out what the best way to organize those 16 bits in the argument register is. For example, in the original 32-bit number, if the 16 bits were in the middle, I might shift them so the rightmost is in LSB, and put that in $a0

Comment: Getting clearer... but show actual code. To load a 32 bit register you normally need to provide a 32 bit value. If you want to change just the top 4 bits, you might AND the register with (your four bits) followed by (28 ones). Which itself would be `fourBits<<28 | 0x0FFFFFFF`

Comment: I actually just had the realization that instead of shifting the numbers all the way to the LSB, I can just "send" the whole number in addition to a second input parameter that tells the function at which digit to do its work. I think that's probably a better solution than shifting.

Comment: Yes that is a much better approach. Sometimes just explaining a problem clears it up for yourself, doesn't it.